# When using boto3 client.start_workflow_run() the lambda runs during all workflow process time?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-glue

I am planning to use lambda to trigger a glue workflow. I read the fallowing documentation, https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.start_workflow_run, but I doesn't understood if the lambda will just start the workflow and finish or if the lambda will run through all the workflow running time

````
import json
import boto3

# create glue client
client=boto3.client('glue')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("lambda working")
    response = client.start_workflow_run(Name='workflowName')
    print(json.dumps(response, indent=4))```
````

Answer (score 1):

This will work asynchronously. The Lambda will not wait until the Workflow has finished. It will just start it and then exit.